# Is there an easy way to recreate the WinForms layout experience at runtime for user positioning of controls

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, layout, editor

When laying out a WinForm in Visual Studio you get the ability to resize and align your controls very easily with drag handles and border alignment hints.

I'd like to do the same with a runtime control to enable the user to position an image on a page.

For example, if the user has a photo and they want to place it as a background on the desktop I'd like the control to help them move and size the photo thumbnail in a mini desktop visual.

I can do all of this, but my real question is, does anyone know of a way to inherit from the standard WinForms layout editor so that I can choose to use the nice docking, alignment hints and control resizing without coding it all again?

Thanks in advance

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about easy, but you can host the actual winforms designer in your own applications without too many problems.. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx).